# How to set database cluster arguments (like password) with terraform?

Tags: terraform, mysql, provisioning, digital-ocean

I deploy a `digitalocean_database_cluster` with Terraform. It's working and I can connect to it with the username and password that Terraform generates in .tfstate

I want to set a **concrete** username, password, and port. I'm reading the [DO documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/terraform/reference/resources/database_cluster/), but I don't see these arguments, so:

Is my strategy wrong (can't force a concrete value) or there's another way/resource to this?

PS: I'm new to Terraform